# Wakanda v1.1.3 breaks getValue()

Tags: wakanda

Create a protoType page. Add a textInput widget ('textInput1').

`$$('textInput1').getValue()` generates an error in Chrome:

> cannot read property 'getValue()' of undefined.

I am getting the same issue with setValue.

Is there a syntax or method that may avoid this?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Specifically I would like to see when and where you call `getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

`getValue()` and `setValue()` have been replaced on v2 widgets with `.value()`